# Ternary conditional operator inside std::cout

Tags: c++, cout, conditional-operator

Here's my code:

```
std::cout << "The contaner is " << (!container)?"not":; "empty";
```

Which obviously doesn't work but I hope the idea is clear now. I want to print `"The container is empty"`, and to add `"not"` before `"empty"` if `bool` `container` is `false`.

I'd like to know if it's possible or if I have to write something along the lines of:

```
if(container) std::cout ...;
else std::cout ...;
```

Comment: pleae dont assume that things are obvious, instead you should post a [mcve] and the compiler error. With some (very nasty) hacks I am certain that that line can be made to work.

Comment: Note that you also appear to have a stray semicolon midway through your ternary operator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're almost there. The ternary operator will need the `else` result, you can use an empty string `""`, then, due to precedence issues you will need to encapsulate the expression with parenthesis:

```
std::cout << "The contaner is " <<  (!container ? "not" : "") << "empty";
```

Answer (score 5):

When all else fails, just use an if statement:

```
std::cout << "The contaner is ";
if (!container)
    std::cout << "not ";
std::cout<< "empty";
```

Personally I like this better then using the conditional operator as it's easier for me to read.  This also works when the types of the things you want to display are different.  The conditional operator requires that both cases be converted to a common type so something like `!container ? "not" : 1` wont work.

Answer (score 3):

Try ... `<< (!container ? "not" : "") << "empty"`.

Comment: Try?  Why?  [Do you think it will work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196187/is-try-this-bad-practice)? Why?

Answer (score 3):

You can add the empty string in the non-empty case.

```
std::cout << "The container is " << (!empty ? "not ": "") << "empty";
```

Or turn down the cleverness level a bit, which I personally find more readable,

```
std::cout << "The container is " << (empty ? "empty": "not empty");
```

Comment: ... and a clever compiler will make the `const char*` to "empty" point at the "empty" inside "not empty".

Comment: @TedLyngmo: But obfuscation when done by human: `"not empty" + (empty ? 4 : 0)` :-)

Comment: @Jarod42 :-) Indeed!